# IOS how to add AFNetworking to my xcode project in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS and not able to add `AFNetworking` library to my project [I just followed this link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-made-easy-with-afnetworking--mobile-10741) but I can't add `AFNetwoking` in my project.  Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: since you are new I think you need to read up on cocoa pods as well [here](https://cocoapods.org/). Then you can use that to have afnetworking(link [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)) added to your projectfile

Comment: Use `NSURLSession` instead.

Comment: Use cocoaPods to install AFNetworking

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial,check this,it may helps

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
Download AFNetworking framework from above link. Drag & drop framework in your project and use it. 
Or
You can use cocoapods to have AFNetworking added to your project.